# CSV created by DOS not working on my Regexp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I'm working on my own CSV Reader/Parser which works perfectly with the CSV Files in UNIX format but not with CSV Files in *DOS* format.

I'm using Regexp to control and collect datas from the CSV and I'm sure it's because of the \r\n of DOS cause i didn't put this case in my Regexp.

This is a part of my code with the Regexp which control if the lin in the CSV is valid :

```
var reg_line = new RegExp( "^(([\"]([^\"]|\"\")*[\"])|([^;\"\n]*))([;](([\"]([^\"]|\"\")*[\"])|([^;\"\n]*))?)*$", 'gm' );

var result = this._file_content.match( reg_line );
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `\r` to your regex?

Comment: Yes i did ! I put it just before the \n

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you want to maximize your chances of getting a good answer, you should get rid of all that bold formatting.  It's very distracting.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought it was better for you in contrary but i will be careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remove the /r in the lines before the regex matching with :

```
var test = this._file_content.replace(/\r/g, "");
var result = test.match( reg_line );
```

It will works.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `\r*\n` as end of line in your regex. This will check windows on unix eol.

Comment: You mean : var reg_line = new RegExp( "^(([\"]([^\"]|\"\")*[\"])|([^;\"\n]*))([;](([\"]([^\"]|\"\")*[\"])|([^;\"\r*\n]*))?)*$", 'gm' ); ? Because it's not working :/

Comment: @Jens This allows multiple `\r`, which seems odd.  Truly 'correct' approach for this would surely be `(\r\n|\r|\n)`, which would also cover Mac line endings, but without allowing `\n\r`, which should not occur.